# How do I use kotlin to move an ImageView diagonally using animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I am tring to move an animation diagonally across the view using animation.
I am using Android Studio Girrafe and kotlin

Any one help?
Is there another way to do this?

I have looked at ObjectAnimator but cannot see a way of changing the x and y at the same time.
I have tried using two ObjectAnimators but not been successful so far and seems klunky.
I have thought about using Path but have not been able to work out how I can use that for diaganol directions so am stuck.

Comment: Can you share the code that fails with two ObjectAnimators.

Comment: I have moved on to using direct image movement instead of animation but that does not give me a smooth result. I had created two animation variables and started them one after the other and the effect was jagged movement.